# Unstable hector_quadrotor above a given height

Tags: ros, physics, ros-fuerte

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can anyone see a reason why a simulation would become unstable and subsequently crash because of the position of a robot in Gazebo? The robot in question is the [hector_quadrotor](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor) and when elevated high enough it goes [crazy](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9Gk5iW1PiEoNl9KQ25rR0dIRzA/preview). (See [here](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B9Gk5iW1PiEoMWNhTFNUaHQ3Wjg/preview) as well.)

For reference in this is with Gazebo 1.6.16 (from ubuntu precise ros-fuerte packages)

`sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-hector-quadrotor-apps`

`roslaunch hector_quadrotor_demo outdoor_flight_gazebo.launch`
and

`rostopic pub /cmd_vel geometry_msgs/Twist '[0,0,0.1]' '[0,0,0]'`

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49960/unstable-hector_quadrotor-above-a-given-height/) by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 2022 on 2012-12-08

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) on 2012-12-12**:
I could not reproduce the problem. I assume you are using the default configuration that comes with the ubuntu packages. You can try to remove the stateTopic and imuTopic parameters from the simple controller plugin config, so that it uses pure ground truth information from gazebo for control.

**Comment by [SL Remy](https://answers.ros.org/users/1001/sl-remy/) on 2012-12-13**:
Commenting out the stateTopic appears to have fixed the issue. Isn't the topic `ground_truth/state` provided by gazebo?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The simple controller plugin takes two parameters `stateTopic` and `imuTopic`, which can be used independently. These parameters are also documented here: http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_quadrotor_controller#XML_Parameters.

If `imuTopic` (sensor_msgs/Imu) is set, the controller plugin subscribes to that topic and uses the orientation and angular rates within for control. The velocity and its derivation are taken from a (nav_msgs/Odometry) message on topic  `stateTopic`. If only `stateTopic` is non-empty, the orientation and angular rates are also taken from the Odometry message. When one or both of the parameters are empty, the plugin uses ground truth information from the Gazebo API to control the quadrotor.

The plugin configuration provided by `quadrotor_simple_controller.urdf.xacro` sets `stateTopic` to `ground_truth/state`, which is published by the gazebo_ros_p3d plugin, and the `imuTopic` to `raw_imu`, which is published by the hector_gazebo_ros_imu plugin. Both plugins can add noise to make the quadrotor flight more realistic. Instead of using the ground truth state directly you can also use the [hector_localization](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_localization) stack that implements an Extended Kalman Filter to fuse all available measurements (IMU, Magnetometer, Pressure, GPS) to a combined pose estimate which can be fed into the controller using the `stateTopic` parameter.

Coming back to the problem: If the quadrotor is instable when using ground_truth/state as `stateTopic` and stable if the parameter is empty, it seems that some messages are lost or there is too much latency between the p3d and the controller plugin. As the publisher and subscriber are running in the same process, roscpp uses intra-process links and until now I was not aware of problems with latency or dropped messages.

You could add a debug output in the GazeboQuadrotorSimpleController::StateCallback() method to check latency (by comparing the timestamp with Gazebo's current SimTime) and if messages get lost (by looking at the seq number).

Note that the GazeboQuadrotorSimpleController plugin has been moved back from package `hector_quadrotor_controller` to package `hector_quadrotor_gazebo_plugins` in the SVN trunk recently.

---

Originally posted by [Johannes Meyer](https://answers.ros.org/users/1634/johannes-meyer/) with karma: 1266 on 2012-12-13

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1